# Showing file name when in full screen mode in Intelij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Intelij Idea does hides every thing when in full screen mode so that the developer can make use of maximum screen space available for writing code. From the documentation:

> In Full Screen mode, IntelliJ IDEA expands the main window to occupy
>   the entire screen. All operating system controls are hidden, but you
>   can access the main menu if you hover the mouse pointer over the top
>   of the screen.

I recently embarked on the journey to minimise the use of mouse and therefore have started using the full screen mode. It sometimes happen that I need to know the file name. This is required as we have many files with more or less similar names (eg. `XXXPreMigrationService`, `XXXPostMigrationService`). Now in order to see the file name, I can use different approaches:

- `Alt+1` Shows file in the Project Explorer window.
- `Alt+Home` Shows file in the Navigation toolbar.

Both the approaches require me to press 2 keys (twice). Is it possible to show/hide the current file name by press/un-press any key? Is there a way I can set a shortcut for such action?

Comment: Do you have editor tabs hidden as well? See http://hadihariri.com/2014/06/24/no-tabs-in-intellij-idea/.

Comment: yes :) That where the inspiration came from!

Comment: If you have everything hidden, there doesn't seem to be an action to show the file name with the single key. You can create a plug-in or just enable the persistent navigation toolbar.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for your confirmation.